# Массовая проверка списка url

Tags: python

Есть ли уже такой готовый модуль в питоне? Речь идёт о способности работать с большими файлами списков.

Comment: @Namer, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.

Comment: вот пример кода, который проверяет возможность ssl соединения к списку узлов из файла, используя [`gevent`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4850200/4279), или [`twisted`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4868866/4279), или [`asyncio`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20722204/4279). Код проверялся для миллиона узлов.

Answer (score 2):

есть, два -- `urllib.request` и `concurrent.futures`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example